# I'd like to make it loop again only when all the datas in list fully looped

Tags: python, for-loop, double

I was making stock data calculator. My intention was bring all the datas in one time which in list every year and do the calculation. However, my code did every year calculation on each data. How can I fix it for my original intension? My language is python and the version is 3.8.10 64bit.

Here's my code:

```
.....Python modules

enter pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format


file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 =[ 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022 ] 


 wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
 sheet = wb.active

 b2 = sheet['B2']
 b2.value = 'Name'

 #wb['b2'] = 'Name'


 c2 = sheet['C2']
 c2.value = 'Results' 




 file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')



for i in range(0, 781):  


os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')
odd = file_list[i]
td = pd.read_excel('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel/'+str(odd))
td['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(td['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d' )


for r in range(0,3):
    target_year = list_3[r]
    data = td.query('Date.dt.year == @target_year').copy()





    def calMACD(data, short=5, long=25, signal=9):

        data.sort_index()
        
        data['MVA_25']=data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
        data['MVA_5']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean()
        data['MACD']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean() - data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
        data['Signal']=data['MACD'].ewm(span=signal, adjust=False).mean( )
        #data['Buy_sign']=(data['MACD']-data['Signal']) >=600
        data['Buy_sign']=np.where(data['MACD']-data['Signal'] >=451, 'Buy' , 'Sell' )
        #data['Target_1']=(data['Close']-data['Close'].shift(1))/data['Close'].shift(1)*100
        #data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (data['Change'])+1,1)
        #data['Target_2']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Sell', (data['Change'])+1,1)
        #data['Real_world']= 1000000*data['Target_1']
        #data['Real_world_2']= 1000000*data['Target_2'] 
        #data['Condition'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Real_world']-data['Real_world'].shift(-2),1)
        ##data['Condition_2'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Target_1'].shift(-2),1)
        #data['Moneyflow'] = 
        #plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Real_world'])
        #data[data.Buy_sign !='Sell']
        
        


        return data
    #print(calMACD(data), odd)   




    Adjusted = calMACD(data)
    Adjusted.drop(['Change'], axis=1, inplace = True)
    Filtered = Adjusted[Adjusted.Buy_sign!='Sell'].copy()

    #print(Filtered)
    #Filtered = (Adjusted.Buy_sign =='Buy') #(Adjusted.Condition = 1.0)
    #Master = Adjusted.loc[Adjusted,['Date','Buy_sign','Target_1','Real_world',]]
    #print(Adjusted)


    def backtester(Filtered):
        Filtered['Change'] = ((Filtered['Close'] - Filtered['Close'].shift(1)) / Filtered['Close'].shift(1))+1
        #data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (data['Change'])+1,1)
        Filtered['Real_world'] = 1000000*Filtered['Change']
        #Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Real_world'].shift(-2)-Filtered['Real_world'],1)
        Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Change'].shift(-2),1)
        #Filtered['Target_1'] = np.where(Filtered['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (Filtered['Change'])+1,1)
        #Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Real_world'].shift(-2)-Filtered['Real_world'],1)

        return Filtered 
    
  



    s = backtester(Filtered)

    e = s[s.Condition!=1.00000]

    x = e.dropna()

    y = x['Condition']



    list_2.append(odd)




    try:
        geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12

    except StatisticsError as e:
        a = ('Sell is empty')
        list_1.append(a)

    else:
        d = (geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)
        print(d,odd)
        list_1.append(d)
        #write_ws.append(list_1)
        #write_wb.save('/home/sejahui/results.xlsx')
        print(list_1)






    
    for i in range(0,790):

        sheet['C'+str(3+i)] = list_1[i]
        sheet['B'+str(3+i)] = list_2[i]
        wb.save('/home/sejahui/result(2)/results.'+str(target_year)+'.xlsx')
        #re = pd.read_excel('/home/sejahui/results(2)/results.xlsx')
        #print(re)
```

Comment: You cannot expect us to decipher and debug 150+ lines of your code. Be specific, your title has no relation with your question body

Answer (score 0):

2 hints: your def functions should not be in for loops, it makes no sense to declare it everytime. Do it like this:

```
def calMACD(data, short=5, long=25, signal=9):
    ...
    ...
def backtester(Filtered):
    ...
    ...
for r in range(0,3):
    ...
    ...
```

also it looks like you did not indent the content of your first for loop. Try this:

```
for i in range(0, 781):  
    os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')
    odd = file_list[i]
    td = pd.read_excel('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel/'+str(odd))
    td['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(td['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d' )
```